# Unexpected memory value change

Tags: c, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm new to C and I've created a small structure:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
  union {
    char *string;
    char *filename;
  } x;
} my_struct_t;
```

I have these functions to create and release `my_struct` instances:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

my_struct_t *build_struct(){
  my_struct_t *obj;
  obj = malloc(sizeof(my_struct_t));
  obj->x.filename = NULL;
  obj->x.string   = NULL;
  return( obj );
}

void free_all(my_struct_t *obj){
  char *string = obj->x.string;
  char *filename = obj->x.filename;
  if (string) free(string);
  if (filename) free(filename);
  free(obj);
}
```

However, when I can't use them successfully.  Here's my test program:

```
void modify_struct(my_struct_t *obj, const char *value){
    char *temp = malloc(strlen(value));
    memcpy(temp,value,strlen(value));
    obj->x.filename = temp;
}

int main(){
  my_struct_t *obj = build_struct();
  modify_struct(obj,"invented string");
  free_all(obj);
  return 0;
}
```

I dynamically allocate the struct setting both `string`, and `filename` to `NULL`.  I then change the value of `filename`, before freeing the memory.

During the call to `free_all()`, it seems that `string` is not `NULL` any more so both 'if' conditions succeed, and the program attempts to free a non-allocated memory.

Why does this happen, even though I never touched `string`?  And how can I fix it?

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `then I tried to change the value of filename, and then freeing the memory`..fishy. how do you "change"?

Comment: Just set one char* to NULL and read what union actually is.

Comment: It seems you didn't understand `union` well. Go fetch a good book and read it.

Comment: @Toby Speight I've already fixed my code. The problem was not a missing #include, but an incorrect use of unions. If it is possible, someone could help me to mark this question as CLOSED or SOLVED? I haven't managed to find anything about

Comment: @Max, if you have found a solution, you normally add an answer explaining the cause (or, if such an answer already exists, mark it accepted - which you've done).  You can't do that while the question is on hold; you'll need to make your example code reproducible and wait for it to be reopened before you can add your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Rule of thumb:** You ***only*** free memory which was allocated by allocator functions (`malloc()` and family).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3, (*emphasis mine*)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, **if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function**, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, **the
>   behavior is undefined.**

In your case, you attempt to free `obj->x.filename` which is a pointer to a *string literal*, was not returned by allocator function. So, passing that to `free`, your code invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, the syntax

```
 if (string) {
      free(string);
 }
```

does not make much sense, as passing a `NULL` pointer to `free()` is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @Max In a `union`, all members start at the same address.  This means that anytime you change `filename` you also change `string`.  They will *always* contain the same data.   So you should only operate on one at a time.

Comment: @dbush that makes me clearer how unions work. I totally misunderstood their meaning. I'm going to replace the keyword 'union' with 'struct'.